# Integral with bilinear forms in exponent

Tags: integration, bilinear-form, trigonometric-integrals

I've encountered the following integral:
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi d\omega \exp\{ \sum_{i,j=1}^n R_j H_{ij}^c(\omega) d_i  + \sum_{i,j=1}^n I_j H_{ij}^s(\omega) d_i \},$$
where $R_j, I_j, d_i$ are reals and
$$ H_{ij}^c = \cos(ij \omega),\\H_{ij}^s = \sin(ij \omega).$$

I don't necessarily expect a closed form but I thought it couldn't hurt to ask here.

The integral is of the form $\int f(\cos \omega, \sin \omega) d\omega$ since we can expand the $H$-matrices in $c_{pq}\cos^p(\omega)\sin^q(\omega)$ form (being multiple-angle relations). I've tried this and the substitutions $u = \sin \omega, z = \tan(\omega/2)$ but this integral seems way above my math level. I would be very grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I tried for $n=2$ with a similarity transform (for now) but the resulting $\vec R' \cdot \vec d'$ with $R_i' = f(\vec R, \omega), d_i' = g(\vec d, \omega)$ does not simplify or generalize easily. Also Maxima crashes my laptop for $n=3$. I guess what is weird here is that the integration is over the coefficient matrix and not over the vectors. Thanks for the reply; do you maybe have any other advice?

Comment: @Chickenmancer if the bilinear form is symmetric (resp. Hermitian) your statement is true.  In general, however, any square matrix can represent a bilinear form, and nilpotent matrices are not diagonalizable.